# Activity main doesn't display title bar

Tags: java, xml, android-fragments

i'm trying to develop a simple app including a Fragment (first time I use it ). The problem is the XML of my activity main does not display the title bar, maybe i'm doing something wrong with the Fragment,can't understand what.

MainActivity.java :

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       if(savedInstanceState==null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment, new ForecastFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind.app.Activities.ForecastFragment"
    tools:context=".app.Activities.ForecastFragment">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind.app.Activities.ForecastFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment_main.xml :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ForecastFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

content_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_forecast"
android:name="com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind.app.Activities.ForecastFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 />
```

ForecastFragment.java

```
    public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment() {}

    String[] forecastArray = {
            "Today - Sunny - 31/20",
            "Tomorrow - Sunny  - 42,30",
            "Wednesday - Rainy - 20,15",
            "Thursday - FINIMONDO - 35,20"
    };
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedIstanceState ){
        super.onCreate(savedIstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View  rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,list);
        ListView lw = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        lw.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater ) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if( id == R.id.action_refresh ) {
            FetchWeatherTask fetchWeatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            fetchWeatherTask.execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

logcat on start :

```
    08-10 12:22:55.397 2311-2311/com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-10 12:22:55.397 2311-2311/com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-10 12:22:55.433 2311-2311/com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind-1/lib/x86
08-10 12:23:01.545 2311-2311/com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind-1/lib/x86
08-10 12:23:01.725 2311-2747/com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-10 12:23:01.725 2311-2747/com.example.sgrumo.sunshineonyourmind D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
```

Comment: I added to the activity main.xml this line : 
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main", so the design of the XML for the main activity is perfect but using the emulator i still get no title bar and 2 overlapped ListView

Comment: can you post the entire code, the given code should not affect actionBar visibility and should appear on top of the Activity.

Comment: @AmanSinghal I've added the code. I don't know why I still get 2 ListView, overlapped

Comment: Cause you are adding two `ListVies`s, one in the `activity_main` using the `<fragment>` and one from the fragment that you are adding to `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @MaskedMan Right, thanks! But I still don't understand why I have not a title bar!

Comment: @sgrumo, which title bar do you mean?
the one that usually displays the app name?

Comment: @MaskedMan, Yes. in every desing of my XML it appears the bar name with the App name (which is SunshineOnYourMind in this case), but when I run the app it doesn't display it.

Comment: It's because in older apps you made your `activity` subclass of `AppComaptActivity` I think (Which is android studio's default when creating projects) but `FragmentActivity` is a subclass of `Activity`.

Comment: Mmmh so? What can I do? I've tried to extends AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity but still no bar on top of the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120686/discussion-between-sgrumo-and-masked-man).

Comment: Have you tried changing the `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` to `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: That's what I said in the last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a couple of hours trying to debug my app, i've started again the project choosing an empty activity. Now everything is perfect!